# How to generate simple jwt using secret key for supabase

Tags: supabase, deno

I'd like to generate a short lived service_role jwt key using the jwt secret, but I'm having trouble finding a simple example of this being done. here's my current code:

```
import { getEnvOrExplode } from "./env.ts";
import { create, getNumericDate } from "https://deno.land/x/djwt/mod.ts";

export const generateArbitraryRoleJWT = async (
  role:
    | "service_role"
    | "billing_admin"
    | "project_admin"
    | "stripe_admin"
    | "usage_plage_admin"
    | "usage_meter_admin",
  expirySeconds = 60
) => {
  const payload = {
    iss: "supabase",
    ref: getEnvOrExplode("REFERENCE_ID"),
    role: role,
    iat: getNumericDate(0),
    exp: getNumericDate(expirySeconds),
  };

  return await create(
    {
      alg: "HS256",
      typ: "JWT",
    },
    payload,
    getEnvOrExplode("JWT_SECRET")
  );
};
```

But it's complaining because it seems I need to create a different kind of key than the string jwt_secret?

Comment: You can't use a string directly as a key. In my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494966/jwt-authentication-with-deno I show how to create a key with crypto.subtle.

Comment: so my use case is impossible?

Comment: Impossible? You just can't use the "JWT_SECRET" directly, but need to create a key from it, as shown in the linked Q/A, and then use the created key instead of the secret.

Answer (score 0):

from [JWT authentication with Deno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494966/jwt-authentication-with-deno)

```
import { getEnvOrExplode } from "./env.ts";
import { create, getNumericDate } from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v3.0.1/mod.ts";

const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const keyBuf = encoder.encode(getEnvOrExplode("JWT_SECRET"));

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  keyBuf,
  { name: "HMAC", hash: "SHA-256" },
  true,
  ["sign"]
);

export const generateArbitraryRoleJWT = async (
  role:
    | "service_role"
    | "billing_admin"
    | "project_admin"
    | "stripe_admin"
    | "usage_plan_admin"
    | "usage_meter_admin",
  expirySeconds = 60
) => {
  const payload = {
    iss: "supabase",
    ref: getEnvOrExplode("REFERENCE_ID"),
    role: role,
    iat: getNumericDate(0),
    exp: getNumericDate(expirySeconds),
  };

  return await create(
    {
      alg: "HS256",
      typ: "JWT",
    },
    payload,
    key
  );
};
```